Golang HTTP Handler -- is it possible to implement a call and response pattern within a single streaming POST?
I have very large sets of data on mobile and desktop clients that I am trying to bi-directionally sync with my website.
I have currently setup a stream, where I am sending data up the server in chunks. When each chunk is completed processing and the server has successfully registered that chunk of data, I then need to send back response data which contains registry information that helps keep the server and the client in sync.
After receiving that response, the client will upload another chunk and the process begins again. The data from the client is streamed to the server to keep the client's memory footprint low.
I have tried many combinations to see if I can get this to work. In all cases, if the server writes the response and the client has kept the stream open (awaiting the response from the server to continue) then I don't receive the servers response until it's connection timeouts.
So is there a way to do this within a stream?
Send data - receive response
Send more data - receive response
And so on...?
Below is a small contrived sample on how I've been able to successfully read the streamed data, but not send multiple responses back. NOTE: The actual implementation doesn't send a response on every newline, it's just a simplification for demonstration purposes
func UserSyncHandler(db *psql.Database, cache *serverCache.Cache) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {  
        reader := bufio.NewReader(r.Body) 
        for {
            line, err := reader.ReadBytes('\n')
            if err != nil {
                if err == io.EOF {
                    logger.Info("Received EOF")
                    break // naturally reached end of stream
                }
                writeError(w, "Failed to read from sync stream", err, http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }
            // Send response here
            writeData([]byte("confirmation data"))
        }
    }
}


Thank you so much for the clue! I will look there!

Ya that line is supposed to be in the loop! It is in my actual implementation too. Thanks for pointing that out!

@LeGEC and Ceris Limon your two comments appear to have gotten me on the right track!

Thank you so much to LaGec and Cerise Limón
Below is a modified, contrived example showing how I was able to get it to work.
func UserSyncHandler(db *psql.Database, cache *serverCache.Cache) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    
        // Added as noted in a comment
        controller := http.NewResponseController(w)
        _ = controller.EnableFullDuplex() // no error reported 
  
        reader := bufio.NewReader(r.Body) 
        for {
            line, err := reader.ReadBytes('\n')
            if err != nil {
                if err == io.EOF {
                    logger.Info("Received EOF")
                    break // naturally reached end of stream
                }
                writeError(w, "Failed to read from sync stream", err, http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }
            // Send response here
            writeData([]byte("confirmation data"))
            // Added as noted in another comment
            controller.Flush()
        }
    }
}


Some feedback: respond with internal server error if call to EnableFullDuplex fails; handle error from writeData; handle error from Flush.

Definitely I just limited all of that to illustrate how to get the communication working. It isn’t the actual implementation I wrote


Websocket does not support h2

sse is a one-way stream, and low-version Go timeout does not support it

Refer to sse implementation


Please run it:
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

const (
    HeaderAccept           = "Accept"
    HeaderCacheControl     = "Cache-Control"
    HeaderConnection       = "Connection"
    HeaderContentType      = "Content-Type"
    MimeTextEventStream    = "text/event-stream"
    HeaderTransferEncoding = "Transfer-Encoding"
)

type Request struct {
    Index int
}

type Response struct {
    Index int
}

func main() {
    go func() {
        // Wait listen port
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        ch := make(chan *Request, 8)
        ch <- &Request{}

        for {
            resp, err := NewClientStream("GET", "http://localhost:8088/call", ch, func(req *Request, resp *Response) error {
                fmt.Println("client:", req.Index, resp.Index)
                time.Sleep(time.Second*3)
                ch <- &Request{rand.Intn(256)}
                return nil
            })

            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            if resp != nil && resp.StatusCode == http.StatusNoContent {
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    ln ,err := net.Listen("tcp",":8088")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println("listen :8088")

    srv := http.Server{
        // test timeout
        ReadTimeout:  time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:  time.Second,
        Handler: NewHandlerStream(func(req *Request) (any, error) {
            resp := &Response{req.Index + 1}
            fmt.Println("server:", req.Index, resp.Index)
            return resp, nil
        }),
    }
    srv.Serve(ln)
    srv.ListenAndServe()
}

func NewHandlerStream[T any](rpc func(*T) (any, error)) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.Header.Get(HeaderAccept) != MimeTextEventStream {
            return
        }

        w.Header().Set(HeaderContentType, MimeTextEventStream)
        w.Header().Set(HeaderTransferEncoding, "chunked")
        w.Header().Set(HeaderConnection, "keep-alive")
        w.Header().Set(HeaderCacheControl, "no-cache")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        ctl := http.NewResponseController(w)
        ctl.EnableFullDuplex()
        ctl.SetReadDeadline(time.Time{})
        ctl.SetWriteDeadline(time.Time{})
        ctl.Flush()

        de := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
        en := json.NewEncoder(w)
        for {
            // receive
            req := new(T)
            err := de.Decode(req)
            if err != nil {
                return
            }

            resp, err := rpc(req)
            if err != nil {
                return
            }

            err = en.Encode(resp)
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            ctl.Flush()
        }
    }
}

func NewClientStream[T, P any](method, path string, ch chan *P, call func(*P, *T) error) (*http.Response, error) {
    r, w := io.Pipe()
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, path, r)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    req.Header.Set(HeaderAccept, MimeTextEventStream)
    req.Header.Set(HeaderTransferEncoding, "chunked")

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if resp.StatusCode == http.StatusNoContent {
        return resp, err
    }
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return resp, fmt.Errorf("response status code is %d", resp.StatusCode)
    }

    de := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
    en := json.NewEncoder(w)

    for {
        // send request
        data := <-ch
        err := en.Encode(data)
        if err != nil {
            return resp, err
        }

        // receive
        receive := new(T)
        err = de.Decode(receive)
        if err != nil {
            return resp, err
        }

        // handler
        err = call(data, receive)
        if err != nil {
            return resp, err
        }
    }
}

